# ntpq -pn gets timeout, (because i think) nptd doesn't bind to ::1, why?

Tags: ntpd

```
Linux myhost 4.1.12-103.7.1.el7uek.x86_64 #(host edited)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)
ntpd - NTP daemon program - Ver. 4.2.6p5
ntp-4.2.6p5-25.0.1.el7_3.2.x86_64
```

/etc/ntp.conf:

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
restrict default nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1
server someserver iburst #edited
server someserver iburst #edited
includefile /etc/ntp/crypto/pw
keys /etc/ntp/keys
disable monitor
```

ntp is running like this, so no deprecated -I interface options..:

```
ntp      25451  0.0  0.0  25676  4156 ?        Ss   11:27   0:00 /usr/sbin/ntpd -u ntp:ntp -g
```

on startup it says:

```
/usr/sbin/ntpd -n -dd
[...]
Listen and drop on 0 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0 UDP 123
Listen and drop on 1 v6wildcard :: UDP 123
Listen normally on 2 lo 127.0.0.1 UDP 123
Listen normally on 6 vethr9d35e1373f fe80::70f4:4aff:fe83:7639 UDP 123    
[...]
```

and also it says a line like:  `create_interface(fe80::70f4:4aff:fe83:7639#123)` for each interface.. but not for ::1

the /etc/hosts:

```
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6   
localhost6.localdomain6
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
172.27.30.10 hostname1 hostname2
172.27.30.10 hostname3 hostname4
172.27.30.10 hostname5 hostname6
```

now following straces of the ntpq calls on the faulty first and then on a working server:

```
strace ntpq -np |& grep -i conn
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(123), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::1", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNSPEC, sa_data="\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"}, 16) = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(123), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(123), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::1", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = 0
```

and ntpq -pn does NOT WORK:

```
ntpq -pn
::1: timed out, nothing received
***Request timed out
```

on a similar server, with the same /etc/hosts, and same /etc/ntp.conf and same kernel/os/ntp version it has `create_interface(::1#123)` - but not on my server.
any pointers/things to try greatly appreciated.

```
strace ntpq -np |& grep -i conn
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(123), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(123), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::1", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(123), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::1", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = 0
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(123), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(123), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::1", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = 0
```

and ntpq -pn WORKS

Answer (score 1):

For ntp-4.2.6p5 and up try to change `restrict 127.0.0.1`, or `restrict 127.0.0.1 mask ...`, to `restrict localhost`.